# Cannot upload file missing System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, file-upload

I have a web application and I am trying to give users the ability to upload a file but when I test the program, this is the error message I get;

`Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload'.`

I thought this was something that was included in Visual Studio 2010?

Here is a code sample;

```
    Dim txtFile As String

    firstName = FirstNameTextBox.Text
    lastName = LastNameTextBox.Text
    empID = EmpIDTextBox.Text
    newStore = StoreDropDownList.SelectedValue
    newDate = DateTextBox.Text
    altDate = Replace(newDate, "/", "_")
    URL = "https://URL.com/date.pdf"
    txtFile = PDFFileUpload.ToString

    Dim userName As String
    Dim passWord As String
    Dim tempURL As String

    userName = "?????"
    passWord = "?????"
    tempURL = "https://url.com

    My.Computer.Network.UploadFile(txtFile, tempURL, userName, passWord, True, 500)
```

Comment: Are you using the FileUpload control?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line "userName = "?????" - What does it show the value of txtFile when you do that?

Comment: I see where you are headed with this. the txtFIle = PDFFIleUpload.ToSTring is incorrect. I changed it and its working now. Thanks!\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your

```
txtFile = PDFFileUpload.ToString()
```

If you have this correct, I am sure it can find the file.